# Format number to currency in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, formattable

I am looking to format **Quote dollars** number to a currency format within dplyr verbs with no cents included. Rounded up to the nearest dollar. Here is the code I have so far and its output. How can I get quote dollars to go from a number (1000.5 to $1001)?

```
$ ADD_PROD_DESC          <chr> NA, NA, "Copper White 147-1472G", "Copper White 147-1472G", "Copper White 147-1472G", "Copper White 147-1472G", "Copper White 147-1472G", "Copper White~
$ Manufacturer_Model_NBR <chr> NA, "1404N42-00", "147-1472G", "147-1472G", "147-1472G", "147-1472G", "147-1472G", "147-1472G", "147-1472G", "147-1672G", "147-1672G", "147-1672G", "14~
$ Call_For_Price         <chr> "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE~
$ Quote_Dollars          <dbl> 1784781.3, 1008000.0, 746010.0, 703822.5, 703822.5, 703822.5, 703822.5, 646818.5, 646818.5, 613302.3, 560757.6, 560757.6, 560757.6, 560757.6, 519990.0,~
```

Comment: Unlike excel you have to convert numeric to string in this case.  Use `paste0` or `stringr::str_c()`  like `paste0('$', round(Quote_Dollars,0))`

Comment: how would I do this with dplyr verbs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the package `scales`:

```
Quote_Dollars <- scales::dollar_format()(data$Quote_Dollars)
```

`dollar_format` round to the closest by default.

Comment: if I did this within dplyr would I have to do this in the mutate verb?

Comment: You would have to do:
`data <- data %>% mutate(Quote_Dollars = dollard_format()(data$Quote_Dollars))`

Comment: @MonJeanJean Should it be `dollar_format` instead of `dollard_format`?

Comment: @jpdugo17 You're right, thanks. I'll edit then

Answer (score 4):

You may do like this in `dplyr` pipes.  **But you have to be careful to do this in last of your pipe, as it/these will convert `numeric` to `string` and you won't be able to perform further calculations on these.**

```r
set.seed(123)
Quote_Dollars <- sample(7000:20000, 5)/7
df <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:5],
                 col2 = letters[6:10],
                 Quote_Dollars = Quote_Dollars)
df
#>   col1 col2 Quote_Dollars
#> 1    A    f      1351.714
#> 2    B    g      1358.571
#> 3    C    h      2488.286
#> 4    D    i      2245.286
#> 5    E    j      2783.143
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
df %>% mutate(Quote_Dollars = paste0('$', round(Quote_Dollars,0)))
#>   col1 col2 Quote_Dollars
#> 1    A    f         $1352
#> 2    B    g         $1359
#> 3    C    h         $2488
#> 4    D    i         $2245
#> 5    E    j         $2783
```

---

As suggested by MonJeanJean, this should also work.

```
df %>% mutate(Quote_Dollars = scales::dollar(Quote_Dollars, largest_with_cents = 0))
  col1 col2 Quote_Dollars
1    A    f        $1,352
2    B    g        $1,359
3    C    h        $2,488
4    D    i        $2,245
5    E    j        $2,783
```

Comment: I have revised my question,  how would I do it within my dplyr statement?